# Can't set context to resolvers in apollo server

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-modules

Hello I'm new to GraphQl and to Apollo Server.
I would like to implement authentication on my project.

But

For some reason, I can't seem to set context on my resolvers in apollo server.

Here's my index

```
    const server = new ApolloServer({ 
        typeDefs, 
        resolvers, 
        context: ({ req }) => {
           const userId = jwtDecode(req.headers.authorization)
           return userId.sub
        }
    })
```

And my query

```
    Query: {
        users: async (parent, args, context) => {
            try {
                console.log(context)
                return await getUsers(context)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                throw new Error(err.message)
            }
        }

When I try to output the context the result is always like this...


{ injector:
   Injector {
     options:
      { name: 'index.ts_8346047369535445_SESSION',
        injectorScope: 'SESSION',
        hooks: [Array],
        children: [] },
     _classMap: Map {},
     _factoryMap: Map {},
     _applicationScopeInstanceMap:
      Map {
        Symbol(ModuleConfig.index.ts_8346047369535445) => undefined,
        [Function] => undefined },
     _sessionScopeInstanceMap: Map { [Function: ModuleSessionInfo] => [ModuleSessionInfo] },
     _applicationScopeServiceIdentifiers:
      [ Symbol(ModuleConfig.index.ts_8346047369535445), [Function] ],
     _requestScopeServiceIdentifiers: [],
     _sessionScopeServiceIdentifiers: [ [Function: ModuleSessionInfo] ],
     _hookServiceIdentifiersMap: Map {},
     _name: 'index.ts_8346047369535445_SESSION',
     _injectorScope: 'SESSION',
     _defaultProviderScope: 'SESSION',
........
```

Comment: can you add the code to `jwtDecode`  method?

Comment: Hello! I'm just using the jwt-decode module on npm

Comment: what does `userId` holds? can you console log it and check what it prints? I think there might be a problem with the `req.headers.authorization` (token) you are decoding.

Comment: Here's the decoded token
**{ iss: 'https://test-api.auth0.com/',
  sub: 'wNfr5wYesnNYSUGObOP6l64FzdMrSulB@clients',
  aud: 'https://test-api.auth0.com/api/v2/',
  iat: 1584351388,
  exp: 1584437788,
  azp: 'wNfr5wYesnNYSUGObOP6l64FzdMrSulB',
  scope:
   'read:client_grants....**

Comment: Tried to returning a string for the context, still the same error.

Comment: Are you using [GraphQL Modules](https://graphql-modules.com/) to create your schema?

Comment: Yes!! I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's returned inside the `context` function should always be an object. So you would do something like

```
context: ({ req }) => {
  const { sub } = jwtDecode(req.headers.authorization)
  return {
    sub,
  }
}
```

and then access the value inside the resolver by calling `context.sub`.

However, if you're using GraphQL Modules to create your schema, you should follow the library's [documentation](https://graphql-modules.com/docs/introduction/context) for configuring your context on a per-module basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The problem is because of the graphql modules, would def read the documentation